# babel syntax error while building the project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I am trying to build a react app using npm run build.
If i just try and build the front end I am able to build it but I am not able to build the full project.

This is the error that I am getting.

```
> dixit@1.0.0 build

> rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./.babelrc,./package.json,./npm-debug.log --copy-files

SyntaxError: /home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/front/node_modules/@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx-experimental/src/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (131:52)

129 |
130 |           if (file.ast.comments) {

> 131 |             for (const comment of (file.ast.comments: Array\<Object\>)) {
> |                                                     ^
> 132 |               const sourceMatches = JSX_SOURCE_ANNOTATION_REGEX.exec(
> 133 |                 comment.value,
> 134 |               );
> at constructor (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:356:19)
> at Parser.raise (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3223:19)
> at Parser.unexpected (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3253:16)
> at Parser.expect (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3590:28)
> at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11490:14)
> at Parser.parseExprAtom (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11142:23)
> at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10862:23)
> at Parser.parseUpdate (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10845:21)
> at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10821:23)
> at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/home/aditya/Desktop/trading-game-development/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10659:61) {
> code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR',
> reasonCode: 'UnexpectedToken',
> loc: Position { line: 131, column: 52, index: 4006 },
> pos: 4006
> }\
```

my .bablerc file

```
\`{
"presets": \["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"\],
"plugins": \[

          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    
      ]

}\`
```

and my package.js file

```
{
  "name": "dixit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon starter",
    "front": "npm start --prefix front",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run front\"",
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./.babelrc,./package.json,./npm-debug.log --copy-files"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "async-mutex": "^0.2.4",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-device": "^0.4.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.5.0",
    "express-zip": "^3.0.0",
    "gravatar": "^1.8.1",
    "json-2-csv": "^3.7.6",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.10",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/del": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/lokijs": "^1.5.3",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6",
    "webpack": "4.42.0"
  }
}
```

The image is my directory

[image]

Also the package.js file of front (given the directory in image)

```
\`{
"name": "front",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"i": "^0.3.6",
"npm": "^6.14.7",
"rc-time-picker": "^3.7.3",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-ace": "^8.1.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.2.0",
"react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
"react-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.3.7",
"react-detect-offline": "^2.4.0",
"react-device-detect": "^1.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-images-upload": "^1.2.8",
"react-player": "^2.6.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"use-sound": "^1.0.2"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
"production": \[
"\>0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
\],
"development": \[
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
\]
},
"devDependencies": {
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
},
"proxy": "https://127.0.0.1:3001"
}
```

If I am running it in my local machine I am able to run it with npm run dev. But while building it throws the error.

I have tried installing and uinstalling the node and npm. I have aldo added the @babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0". I read a lot of instructions on stackoverflow but none seem to solve the issue.

I am beginner in Mern stack and have taken the project for learning purposes. Also while building I was getting webpack mismatch so I explicitly defined the webpack version which then helped me to build the front.